# How to apply predefined regex pattern in spark dataframe?

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have defined a regex to extract the host name from one log file as:

```
val host = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+".r
```

But when I'm trying to apply this pattern in a spark dataframe it throws an error:

```
df.withColumn(col("hostname"),regexp_extract("value",host,1)).show(5)
```

Error:

> :28: error: type mismatch; found : scala.util.matching.Regex required: String df.withColumn(col("hostname"),regexp_extract("value",host,1)).show(5)

How can I apply a predefined regex pattern to the column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the error, you have:

> type mismatch; found: scala.util.matching.Regex required: String

The `host` variable is of type `Regex` while the Spark function `regexp_extract` expects a string.

To solve this, simply remove the `.r` when creating `host` to keep the variable as a string:

```
val host = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+"
```